# Bluetooth bluez pairing without matching the autogenerated PIN on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, bluetooth, bluez

I am trying to pair two devices without clicking on "match" on both devices for each pairing cycle. How can I set my own constant PIN? My Devices which should be connected is Notebook and a Smartphone.

I am using Python bluez on ubuntu.

Comment: If you are using simple-agent tool provided in bluez, add capability=NoInputNoOutput as a parameter when starting this py tool, it will follow SSP without any user input

Comment: ty for the answer. I added the parameter to etc/bluetooth/main.conf, but theire was no change. Anyway I need a fixed PIN code for pairing, so I can always type the same PIN for pairing.

Comment: In case you need to have a fixed pin scenario and your device is BT 2.1, disable SSP

Comment: Thank you! I disabled it with this sudo hciconfig hci0 sspmode 0
Know I want that the PIN is set on the Server site (On my PC) with a fixed PIN. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I could solve that problem!

1. Kill the Bluetooth-Applet:
   sudo killall bluetooth-applet
2. For PIN-Pairing set sspmode to 0:
   sudo hciconfig hci0 sspmode 0
3. I opened the simple-agent, so you can edit the code in RequestPinCode Method the if you want to:
   sudo gedit /usr/local/bin/simple-agent
4. Start simple-agent:
   su -c /usr/local/bin/simple-agent